# change TitledBorder color dynamically in java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, border, titled-border

I have created a TitledBorder and set it to a JPanel.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.
      createTitledBorder(null, "title", javax.swing.border.
      TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION, javax.swing.border.
      TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, null, java.awt.Color.red));
```

now I want to change the color of the title text of the border; and if possible border lines. I see when I change color of the border by the method `titledborder.setTitleColor(theColor);` and `revalidate()` and `repaint()`; the panel on form is not affected. I also created new instance of `thiledBorder` and assign it to the panel; but not effective. Is it necessary to renew the panel, and then set it new a border instance? thank you

Comment: On which component did you call `revalidate()` and `repaint()`? Can I suggest you adjust your code into an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) so that others may experiment?

Answer (score 6):

You don't state how `titledborder` is assigned but this is how it would work:

```
TitledBorder titledBorder = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(...);
panel.setBorder(titledBorder);
```

then at runtime:

```
titledBorder.setTitleColor(theColor);
repaint(); // revalidate not necessry
```

Comment: +1, for noting the difference between revalidate() and repaint(). Since the size of the component doesn't change you can just repaint() it.

Answer (score 1):

If you know your panel has a titled border you can just do this:

```
    TitledBorder titledBorder = (TitledBorder)jPanel1.getBorder();
    titledBorder.setTitleColor(Color.red);
```