# jpanel implementing button behavior

Tags: java, swing

I want to create a radio button that has more components than the default JRadioButton. I'm wondering what the best method is, should I subclass JRadioButton adding my extra components or is it better to subclass JPanel and add the behavior of a radio button as shown below.

```
---------JPanel---------------
- Titel (Label)              -
- RadioButton (JRadioButton) -
- Description (label)        -
------------------------------
```

The whole panel should be focusable and should provide feedback when clicked or has focus.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: *"should provide feedback"*  How exactly?  If the `JRadioButton` is the only focusable element, it will get focus if the panel is focused, but what exactly would change if the user clicks on a `JLabel`?  *"things which are darn easy in WPF seem to be difficult in swing"*  And things which are possible in Swing are impossible in WPF (e.g. creating a cross-platform GUI).  More generally though, you do not encourage people to help by complaining about 'how things are hard in (the language of discussion) as opposed to (some other language)'..

Comment: @AndrewThompson "How exactly?" By setting the border of the JPanel for example: when pressed set lowered border, when released set 'normal' border. This provides the user with visual feedback. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: A JPanel is just a container, it's not a component, therefore you can't attach an ActionListener to a JPanel.

Comment: @Anto but you can add a FocusListener a KeyListener and a MouseListener...should be enough, right?

Answer (score 1):

None of the above.

- Don't extend components unless you genuinely need to extend functionality, especially not merely for decoration.
- Don't confuse the [containment hierarchy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) with the class hierarchy.
- Don't defeat the existing [focus subsystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html) unless you plan to provide your own.
- If you want to alter the appearance of the panel when the radio button's focus changes, do so in a [focus listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html) attached to the button. The background color of an opaque panel is a bound property, so `setBackground()` should be sufficient.

Comment: Some related approaches are cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22417701/230513).